# Vector empty Push_back calls for expected primary-expression before '{' token

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, gcc-warning, push-back

im having trouble with my compiler

Im using codeblocks with gnugcc

and i want to do:

```
table.push_back({""});
```

and it says

> main.cpp|22|error: expected primary-expression before '{' token|

code works in VS and other compilers... What the hell?

```
vector < car > AddCar()
{
    int i;
    vector < car > table;

    string check;
    table.push_back({""});

    for (i = 0; i < table.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "marka: ";
        cin >> table[i].mark;
        cout << "model: ";
        cin >> table[i].model;
        cout << "cena: ";
        cin >> table[i].price;
        cout << endl;
         table.push_back(car());
   ...
```

yes i want an empty pushback

Comment: Are you compiling with the right c++ version in codeblock? You might be using c++98 which won't recognize `{""}` as an initializer for `car`.

Comment: You might be missing C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is occurring because you probably do not have C++11 enabled. For example, consider [this program](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b62FHgtCo8LqA0xK):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Car {
    std::string a;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Car> example;

    example.push_back({""});
}
```

When run with C++98 in GCC 8.2.0, the error shown is:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:12:23: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     example.push_back({""});
                       ^
prog.cc:12:27: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     example.push_back({""});
                           ^
```

Running this with C++11 fixes the error.

Comment: indeed installing new MinGW with c++11 fixed problem

Comment: @Gadzin Please consider marking this answer correct for the sake of other readers who may encounter the same problem!